# Wordpress multi site 500 internal error

Tags: wordpress

Why am I getting this error when I go to my dashboard for my second site.

I am hosting through hostGator manually. I set up a second site at site.com/site2/. The error I get is when I go to www.site.com/site2/wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

this could be the new bug on WordPress 4.2 with php versions < 5.5, it's an issue with the utf8mb4 charset that isn't correctly set for mysql connections ( works only with mysqli ). This prevents WordPress from creating the multisite tables on the database, and therefore only the main site works

the workaround is to define `define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');` in the wp-config.php file

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tables-not-created-error-establishing-a-database-connection